# Why does a character subtracted from anoter character in Java return an integer

Tags: java, int, character

”0123”.charAt(0) – ’0’ returns an integer. What is this integer (and why is it this integer) and in general why does char-char = int?

Comment: what character is '0' - '1'?

Comment: It uses ascii values of characters.

Comment: @wero: `-SOH` (negative start of heading) of course :)

Answer (score 4):

> why is it this integer

Because the compiler can't *guarantee* that the result of the operation would produce a valid character value.  Since characters, bytes, and integers are all implicitly interchangeable... And since integers are the only one of the three which comprises a superset of the possible values of all three... The conversion to integer is the default.

@wero illustrates this in a comment on the question above:

> what character is '0' - '1'?

That is, if you subtract a higher character from a lower character, then you'd have a *negative character*.  Which isn't valid.  A *negative integer*, however, is valid.

Or consider a byte... What if you add the byte 250 to 250?  Both are valid bytes, but the resulting value is not a valid byte.  (Because it's two bytes wide.)  So an integer is needed to contain it.

For *constant* expressions where the compiler can guarantee the value being produced, there may exist (now or in the future) compilers smart enough to maintain that.  (They'd probably even optimize it to a compile-time constant in place of the expression in the code.)  For example:

```
`1` - `0`
```

However, it wouldn't surprise me if even such a compiler would default back to an integer in the use of something like `.charAt()`, since it's no longer a constant expression.  We, as humans, can intuitively infer the constant result of that expression.  But a compiler needs strict and simple rules, and introducing a method invocation would complicate those rules considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Because chars are encoded with ints. See [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For example:

```
int code = 99;
char c = 'c';
int cc = (int) c; //int cc = 99
char sixty_seven = Integer.toString(code).charAt(0); //the char c
```

”0123”.charAt(0) – ’0’ is: From the string `"0123"` with the method `charAt(index)` is taken the first char from the string, namely the `0`. Then we look at the ASCII table and see that the 0 is 48. Then we get 48-48 = 0 after subtraction.

That is possible because JAVA is very much based on C, where there are no Strings (String is an *object*). "Strings" can be read as char arrays. The ints and chars in C are interchangeable (chars are integer type) in the respective range.

Answer (score 1):

Java `char` holds one Unicode/UTF-16 code unit. Many Unicode codepoints need only one code unit in their UTF-16 encoding and these code units are in broad ranges. Therefore, *within those ranges*, a `char` value can be considered a codepoint.

Subtraction between `char` values gives the "distance" between them, which is mostly useful when dealing with the few "well-organized" sequences of codepoints, such as the Basic Latin Letters (A-Z or a-z). It's not generally useful to know the "distance" between a quarter note and a half note or a smiling face and a winking face, ….

The result is an integer because, well, distance on a list of consecutive integers is measured by integers.

Again, this technique is only valid under very strict circumstances. There is always a less limited way to do it.

See the [Unicode Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Also see the documentation for the [java.lang.Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class.